# Pandoc rst displaying control characters

Tags: pandoc, restructuredtext

I'm trying to display a `code-block` after a list element using RST and pandoc. My markup looks like this:

```
4. For the given inputs, my program produces the following output:
   .. code-block::

    298561404
    (0,0)
    john doe 4
```

But the rendered output (`pandoc -o hw.pdf hw.rst`) has the `.. code-block::` in it: [image: rendered document]. I've tried several different varieties of code directives, but they all give the same result. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works if you insert a blank line before the `code-block` directive:

```
4. For the given inputs, my program produces the following output:

   .. code-block::

    298561404
    (0,0)
    john doe 4
```

Another option is to skip `code-block` and simply use two colons at the end of the preceding paragraph (this indicates that the following text block is a [literal block](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#literal-blocks)):

```
4. For the given inputs, my program produces the following output::

   298561404
   (0,0)
   john doe 4
```